# How to parse a predefined subset of form fields with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I want to make a function that converts any form (supplied as `$("#myForm")`) to a parameters object such as `params = {field1: value1, field2: value2, ... }`, where I already know the list `{"field1", "field2", ...}`. The form can have extra fields that should be ignored. We can assume/hope the "required" fields will be there, though :)

I tried `form.serializeArray()` but it returns all the fields and I don't know how to filter out the unnecessary ones without using loops. The other solution is to read them line-by-line. which takes up lots of code space and just doesn't look nice :) Is there any way to do this in one line?

Thanks,

### Edit

Sorry for the late edit. What if I didn't have control over the forms? Isn't there a way to parse them using only JavaScript?

### Edit 2

OK, editing the HTML seems like the easiest way.

Comment: You can parse all the fields in the form with an each loop like `$("#myForm input").each(function(index, element) { /*code*/
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you place a class on all the form elements you want and serialize the form. Like this:

```js
var params = $('#loginForm input.someClass').serialize();
console.log(params);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <form id="loginForm">
    <input name="username" class="someClass" value="user"/>
    <input name="password" class="someClass" value="pass"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
  </form>
```

Here, you serialize all the input elements in the `#loginForm` form having class `someClass`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a reference like class to get all inputs you want to serialize.

Here is a `fiddle` for your reference : https://jsfiddle.net/vaq8k0pe/

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#myForm").not(".exclude").serializeArray();
```

Any input you wanna exclude just give him class exclude

```
<input type="text" class="exclude"/>
```